# Small-caps special character "ḫ"

Tags: sectioning, unicode, small-caps, extended-characters

I have been trying for some time to get the symbol "ḫ" to play nice with XeLaTeX. However, I'm now having trouble using it inside of a chapter title using the `book` class. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twocolumn]{book} % A4 paper and 11pt font size

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands

\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem Text: Baḫdi-Lim}

\setmainfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\section{Problem Text: Baḫdi-Lim}

\end{document}
```

You'll see that the ḫ in the section heading is not replaced by the upper case Ḫ when the font is set to Linux Biolinum. However, both fonts (Biolinum and Computer Modern) are capable of both the upper- and lower-case characters. What should I do to fix this?

EDIT: I am using TexWorks with MiXTeX 2.9, compiling with XeLaTex.

Comment: It looks as if Linux Biolinum doesn’t have that character in small caps.  However, it does have U+032E, the combining breve below.

Comment: Ah - I guess I didn't know how small caps worked. I (wrongly) thought it worked along similar lines to the `\uppercase` command, with correspondences. I had been using a command that used boxes to place a breve below the character, but that didn't play well with the section headings.

Comment: @Thérèse I tried using U+0048 U+032E, but the h is not in small caps anyway.

Comment: @egreg I rarely use this font, and now I remember why: it relies too much on the Private Use Area.  The small H is at U+E058.

Comment: The use of the PUA makes it at least difficult to automate things with `sectsty`, but `sectsty` seems not to interefere if you type U+E058 U+032E directly in the section title. Depending on which font is used in the GUI of your text editor, that input may look nothing like the expected output, but the PDF is OK.

Comment: If you want to use a different font, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e2b/fontsupport.htm will speed up your search, but you’ll still have to examine the fonts to see whether they have it in small caps.  Source Sans Pro has it.

Comment: How should I enter those directly? I am on a windows machine, and I don't think those commands work natively. I also implemented the command I mentioned, and included the `\protect` I had seen mentioned elsewhere, so I do have something, but it would be nice to have another way.

Comment: Not sure what command you’re talking about.  But though I don’t use Windows, I get the impression that, unless you start using a powerful editor like Emacs, you’ll need to choose the character from the Character Map Utility.